# Value of type 'MFMessageComposeViewController' has no member 'setUPIVerificationCodeSendCompletion'

Tags: ios, swift, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to use [setUPIVerificationCodeSendCompletion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller/4240039-setupiverificationcodesendcomple), a new instance method of MFMessageComposeViewController.

While trying to use it I am getting this error:
Value of type 'MFMessageComposeViewController' has no member 'setUPIVerificationCodeSendCompletion'.

The required entitlement(com.apple.developer.upi-device-validation) is also added to the app.

```
import MessageUI

class SendSms {
    
    func createMessageController() -> UIViewController {
        let vc = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        vc.setUPIVerificationCodeSendCompletion { result in
            print("\(result)")
        }
        return vc
    }
}
```

Comment: It's iOS17+, is your target app iOS17+? Do you use the last Xcode15 with it? Strangely the doc appears only in Objective-C and not Swift on the online doc

Comment: @Larme Yes it's iOS17+ and I am using Xcode15. The doc also has a code snippet in swift. It is just above the Objective-C code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we observe the function `setUPIVerificationCodeSendCompletion:` written in **Objective C** language in `MFMessageComposeViewController(UPI)` category class  and your code is written in **swift** language.

So access these method in **swift** class, you have to import `#import <MessageUI/MFMessageComposeViewController+UPI.h>` in your project bridge header.